# Copy and paste string (Hebrew) in PhpStorm is wrong

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Copy and paste string (Hebrew) in PhpStorm is wrong

my string is:

```
user/3453/99/ddf102/2077/BV/⁨צילום תעודת זהות⁩.pdf
```

Describe In image:
[image: screenshot]

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Those are rendering of the special invisible Unicode symbols. In your case looks like they describe the direction control -- http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Bidi_Class_Values (`FSI`  "the first strong isolate control" and `PDI` "terminates an isolate control"). **P.S.** I see the same if I copy+paste that text into Notepad++

Answer (score -1):

Very good question!

You can use this regex to remove non printable chars:

```
preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/u', '', $path);
```

:)